# Spring JPA/Hibernate Saving Only the Child Entity Sometimes

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a parent entity with the following definition:

```
@Entity(name = "parent")
class ParentEntity {

    @Id
    var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    ...
```

a child entity with the following definition:

```
@Entity(name = "child_1"
class ChildEntity1{
    @Id
    var id: String? = null

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    var parentEntity: ParentEntity? = null
}
```

and another child entity with similar definition

```
@Entity(name = "child_2"
class ChildEntity2{
    @Id
    var id: String? = null

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    var parentEntity: ParentEntity? = null
}
```

I have a Jpa Repository created for each entity. My goal is to have the ParentEntity persisted when ChildEntity1 is persisted, but not when ChildEntity2 is persisted. E.g. If I have

```
var parentEntity = ParentEntity()
var childEntity1 = ChildEntity1()
childEntity1.parentEntity = parentEntity
childEntity1Repo.save(childEntity1)
```

The child entity should be inserted along with the parent entity, but if I have

```
var parentEntity = ParentEntity()
var childEntity2 = ChildEntity2()
childEntity2.parentEntity = parentEntity
childEntity2Repo.save(childEntity2)
```

the parent entity should not be persisted, only the childEntity2.
Currently, if I persist any of the child entities, the parent is persisted along with it.

I just want to know if it's possible, and if so how?